# mathematical function on multiple column combinations with similar names in r

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I have repeated measures data for multiple variables. In my MWE systolic blood pressure (SBP) and BMI measured at 0,6, and 12 months, for 4 individuals. I want to create a column for each of these variables for the difference between 0 and 12 months. My real data has many more variables, so I don't want to do this manually for each variable.

```
qdata= structure(list(id = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10), 
    month = c(0, 6, 12, 0, 6, 12, 0, 6, 12, 0, 6, 12), group = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ET", 
    "UC"), class = "factor"), SBP = c(109, 111, 120, 156, 135, 
    145, 111, 127, 112, 148, 143, 142), BMI = c(25.1710291493159, 
    23.7953599048186, 25.3569303985723, 23.0555555555556, 23.2407407407407, 
    23.1481481481481, 25.9278529309747, 26.0434732338999, 26.9973407330327, 
    27.8718238090353, 27.7008310249307, 27.0168598885127)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df1 = qdata%>%pivot_wider(names_from = "month", values_from = -c(id,month, group))

df1

     id group SBP_0 SBP_6 SBP_12 BMI_0 BMI_6 BMI_12
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2 UC      109   111    120  25.2  23.8   25.4
2     3 ET      156   135    145  23.1  23.2   23.1
3     8 UC      111   127    112  25.9  26.0   27.0
4    10 UC      148   143    142  27.9  27.7   27.0
```

I want to produce the following

```
    id group SBP_0 SBP_6 SBP_12 BMI_0 BMI_6 BMI_12 SBP_diff BMI_diff
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     2 UC      109   111    120  25.2  23.8   25.4       11   0.186 
2     3 ET      156   135    145  23.1  23.2   23.1      -11   0.0926
3     8 UC      111   127    112  25.9  26.0   27.0        1   1.07  
4    10 UC      148   143    142  27.9  27.7   27.0       -6  -0.855
```

where `SBP_diff` is `SBP_12- SBP_0` etc.

I think this can be done with `lappy` and `reduce`, but I don't know the syntax to select the needed columns.

Comment: Do you also have `qdata` or you just have `df1`? The work will be easier to do from qdata`. Though its certeinly doable from df1

Comment: `df1 %>% mutate(SBP_diff = SBP_12 - SBP_0, BMI_diff = BMI_12-BMI_0)` should do it

Comment: @Onyambu. I appreciate I could easily do it manually like that, but the question is how to do for multiple variables, not for each variable individually

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr solution.

```
diff_df <- qdata %>%
    filter(month %in% c(0, 12)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    arrange(month) %>%
    mutate(across(-c(month, group), diff, .names = "{.col}_diff")) %>%
    filter(month == 12) %>%
    select(id, SBP_diff, BMI_diff)

df1 %>%
    left_join(diff_df, by = "id")
# A tibble: 4 × 10
     id group SBP_0 SBP_6 SBP_12 BMI_0 BMI_6 BMI_12 SBP_diff BMI_diff
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     2 UC      109   111    120  25.2  23.8   25.4       11   0.186 
2     3 ET      156   135    145  23.1  23.2   23.1      -11   0.0926
3     8 UC      111   127    112  25.9  26.0   27.0        1   1.07  
4    10 UC      148   143    142  27.9  27.7   27.0       -6  -0.855
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly do:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('_12'), .names = '{str_remove(col,"[0-9]+")}diff') - across(ends_with('_0')))
# A tibble: 4 x 10
     id group SBP_0 SBP_6 SBP_12 BMI_0 BMI_6 BMI_12 SBP_diff BMI_diff
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     2 UC      109   111    120  25.2  23.8   25.4       11   0.186 
2     3 ET      156   135    145  23.1  23.2   23.1      -11   0.0926
3     8 UC      111   127    112  25.9  26.0   27.0        1   1.07  
4    10 UC      148   143    142  27.9  27.7   27.0       -6  -0.855
```